# UIScrollView blocks run loop?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I implemented a NSTimer(repeats) and UITableView on the same viewController.

Somehow, when I scroll through the tableView, the run loop seems to stop firing the NSTimer.
The same goes for UITextView, which is also a subclass of UIScrollView.

May I know what is happening here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason that the timer stops firing is that the run loop switches to `UITrackingRunLoopMode` during scrolling and the timer is not added by default to that mode. You can do that manually when you start the timer:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runloop addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[runloop addTimer:timer forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];
```